# Pass multiple variables to a function

Tags: python, json

I'm working on a project where I read a JSON file and retrieve different information associated with an image I'm working on.

I'm stuck on how to pass to my `json-read` function multiple variables and use them to move into my JSON file and retrieve the value that I need (the code works only when I pass 3 variables).

This is a part of the code:

```
class board(object):
  def __init__(self, json, image):
    self.json = json
    self.image = image  


  def extract_json(one,two,three):
    with open('document.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        return data[one][two][three]


  def crop_img(coords):
    im = Image.open('./tabellone.jpg')
    cropped_im = im.crop(coords)        
    return cropped_im

  score_home_coords = extract_json("boxes", "score_home", "coord")
  score_home_crop = crop_img(score_home_coords)
  score_home_crop.save("./images/score_home_cropped.jpg")
  path1 = "./images/score_home_cropped.jpg"
  command = "ssocr-2.16.3/ssocr -d -1 -b black -l red %s" % path1
  score_home = int(subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())

MyAgonism = board('document.json', './tabellone.jpg')
print "Score Home: %s" % MyAgonism.score_home
```

I have created an instance of the class MyAgonism, to which I pass the json file name along with the image file name I have to work on.

**init** receives them, but how to use them inside the 2 class methods? I would like to do something like this:

```
def extract_json(one,two,three):
        with open(SELF.JSON) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
            return data[one][two][three]


def crop_img(coords):
        im = Image.open(SELF.IMAGE)
        cropped_im = im.crop(coords)        
        return cropped_im
```

JSON file sample:

```
{
    "background": "black",
    "foreground": "red",
    "boxes": {
                "time_minutes": {"foreground": "red", "type" : "7segments" , "coord": [267,132,315,182]},
                "time_seconds": {"foreground": "red", "type" : "7segments" , "coord": [327,132,389,182]},
                "score_home" : {"foreground": "red", "type": "7segments", "coord": [204,51,276,101]},
...
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

I need something like this:

```
   def extract_json(self, *args): 
       with open('document.json') as data_file: 
          data = json.load(data_file) 
          return data[args]
```

but all the args are displayed in this way:

> (args1, args2, args3, args4)

and i need instead

> [args1][args2][args3][args4]

to correctly access to my json file with the right keys

---

Fixed, the method was useless. I just used:

```
with open(self.json_path) as f:
    self.d = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had just forgotten to put `self` as first argument in both your class methods:

```
def extract_json(self, one, two, three):
    with open(self.json) as data_file:
        ...

  def crop_img(self, coords):
    im = Image.open(self.image)
    ...
```

Simplified explanation:

- Methods of a class which need to use some variables passed during the
  instanciation (instance specific values) must have `self` as first argument. **These are called
  instance methods.**
- Methods of a class which do not need to access the instance
  attributes, but need to have access to class attributes or methods,
  need to have `cls` as first argument. **These are called class methods.**
- Methods of a class which do not need to access self and only perform
  some logic and return a value, do not need `self`, nor `cls`. **These are
  called static methods.**

Some more explanations [here](http://pythoncentral.io/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python/)

Comment: If i add self as first argument I receive a type error: `extract_json() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)` Any idea for the first question?

Comment: Ok, I've fixed this. Now it works fine, but still have some problems trying to adapt my extract_json function to work with any arguments passed (like in my answer below)